# Canonical asynch callback example with named function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

In his detailed explanation of asynchronous code in this question:
[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) Fabrício Matté gives the following example:

```
// 1. Call helloCatAsync passing a callback function,
//    which will be called receiving the result from the async operation
helloCatAsync(function(result) {
    // 5. Received the result from the async function,
    //    now do whatever you want with it:
    alert(result);
});

// 2. The "callback" parameter is a reference to the function which
//    was passed as argument from the helloCatAsync call
function helloCatAsync(callback) {
    // 3. Start async operation:
    setTimeout(function() {
        // 4. Finished async operation,
        //    call the callback passing the result as argument
        callback('Nya');
    }, 2000);
}
```

I am trying to remove the anonymous function (I find it easier to read & understand the code that way). How should I do that?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You even might want to make the callback passed to `setTimeout` a function declaration as well.

Comment: I would suggest to place the function declaration above the place where the function is used. You code is absolutely valid, but [hoisting](https://speakingjs.com/es5/ch16.html#_variable_declarations_are_hoisted) is a tricky thing and should be used with caution.

Comment: Thanks - moving the code into a new answer, which I'll accept in a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

```
function helloCatAsync(callback,aString){
  setTimeout (function(){
    callback(aString);
    },2000);
}
function shout (param) {
  alert(param);
}
helloCatAsync(shout,'Nya');
```

Comment: Can you please expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?